# Choose rotation facing direction

Tags: unity, rotation

I am rotating a gameobject in Unity so it always faces another gameobject. However I want to be able to decide which side is going to face the target. I want to be able to change the facing point to any of the color sides of the sphere. So for example the yellow point will be facing the target instead of the green.

[image]

Here is my code

```
    private void Update() {
        float singleStep = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 facing_Dir = transform.forward;
        Vector3 targetDirection = target_Ga.transform.position - transform.position;

        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(facing_Dir, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
    }
```

Comment: For the moment I will be using a parent gameobject and position the child to face the correct direction. It isn't a perfect solution, but it is better than to endlessly tinker with Unity rotations

Answer (score 0):

After your calculations on the object to look at the cube, apply a rotation on the `transform`, based on which side you want it to look at.

For example:

```
private void Update() {
    ...
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
    transform.Rotate(90, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

This should make your object "look" at the cube, but then rotate it so that a different side of the object is looking at the cube now.

It's been a while since I last touched Unity, so I haven't tested the code above. You might need to play around with the order on which transformation happens first, but hopefully this can give you the right idea on how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This makes the object spin in random directions and never stopping. I don't really think this idea should work since even if I position the object to the correct rotation, then in the next iteration of the Update that position is going to be changed.  So we have 2 different rotation positions snapping from one to the other constantly. 
Ideally somehow I can make this  Vector3 facing_Dir = transform.forward;  to work with other rotations, rather than just forward